# C++/CLI wrapper is working properly only on x86 machine, I need x64 machine

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, 64-bit, wrapper

I have x64 native C++ library that I have to pass to C# project.
I built C++/CLI wrapper, based on [this tutorial,](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/) and everything was ok.
But, the project compiles only on x86 architecture.
When I tried adding that native C++ library to project, I received runetime error.
Project doesn't work on x64 architecture because wrapper for some reasons requires x86. And, on the other hand, it doesn't work on x86 because that library requires x64.

I have very little experience with C++/CLI, wrappers, and C# in general, and I don't have much idea how to go around this problem.
When tring to compile Solution, I receive runetime error

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Wrapper, Version=1.0.7178.20781, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was ma
de to load a program with an incorrect format..
```

[Link to error documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=netframework-4.8)

Here is my Wrapper

```
using namespace System;
namespace CLI {
    template<class T>
    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    protected:
        T* m_Instance;
    public:
        Wrapper(T* instance)
            :m_Instance(instance)
        {
        }
        virtual ~Wrapper()
        {
            if (m_Instance != nullptr)
            {
                delete m_Instance;
            }
        }
        !Wrapper()
        {
            if (m_Instance != nullptr)
            {
                delete m_Instance;
            }
        }
        T* GetInstance()
        {
            return m_Instance;
        }
    };
}
```

...And here is a C++/CLI class that is using this wrapper

```
//**********************header file***********************

#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "../Core/Core.h"
using namespace System;
namespace CLI
{
    public ref class Model : public Wrapper<Core::Impl>
    {
    public:

        Model();
        bool test();
    };

//**********************Implementation******************************


#include "Model.h"

namespace CLI
{
    Model::Model()
        :Wrapper(new Core::Impl())
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Creating new Impl-wrapper object!!");
    }
    bool Model::test()
    {
        return m_Instance->test();
    }
}
```

Its pretty much exacly the same as from the tutorial that I used.

I can not modify that native C++ library, so it has to work on x64 architecture.
Can you please explain to me, why wrapper doesn't want to compile on x64, but works perfectly on x86, and is there a way to go around this. Perfect answer would provide an example of C++/CLI Wrapper that is working on x64 architecture.
Thanks in advance

EDIT, 
oh, and I forget to add properties of my project so.
OS is Win10 (x64); .NET target framework 4.5.1; Core project(the lowest layer project, not presented here) is built as static .lib, and Wrapper is a dynamic .dll. 
VisualStudio 2017 v15.9.14

Comment: You must obtain an x64 build of the native C++ library to get ahead.  Talk to the library owner.

Comment: @HansPassant
the library is x64. The wrapper for some reasons was building on x86 only. But I manage to solve "wrapper problems" and now it builds on x64 the same as library. Even though, when compiling solution I still receive the same runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your project setting, especially linker. Check *Command line* tab for linker. Recently I encountered wild X86 flag there in *Additional options* that gave me similar errors.

In advanced, check *Target machine*.

Try to enable verbose output for linker and compiler, and check for any occurrence of x86.

If all of that is ruled out, make sure that your lib was really compiled and is valid, eg. via dependency walker.

Comment: Ok, for those few hours i made some progress. My Wrapper compiles properly now on x64 machine but only if I don't include that native C++ library in Core project.
If I include it, then I have the same runetime error.
For now, it's the end of my job for today and I'm going home, but will certainly check your suggestion tomorow.

Comment: @MateuszBoruch It really sounds like the library you're linking with does not work with your DLL. Try to make a console application instead of DLL and see if it compiles with the external `.lib` and actually does something.

Comment: You mean to create C++/CLI console application instead of C++/CLI Wrapper? I checked it with C++ console app and it worked.

Comment: I'll also only mention that this library is troublesome. It was developed about 6 months  ago, so bugs might appear. Also, it uses ```mutex``` which can not be directly wrapped by C++/CLI. To make it work, I used pointer to implementation technique. I basicly hided ```#include``` in .cpp file, so it never be added in any header. If ```#include``` appears in header, the C++/CLI wrapper doesn't even build (not mentioning compiling)

Comment: @MateuszBoruch pimpl is very correct when wrapping any library. You don't want to expose it's headers in your own DLL. However you really should consider whether you can rebuild the library to be sure the compiler configuration is the same.

Comment: ok, I checked settings, as you suggested and I found something. In C# layer, properties -> build, I found that Target platform was set to "Any CPU", and Platform to "Active(AnyCPU)". I changed Target platform to be x64, but I can't change Platform, because there is no more options than AnyCPU.
I'm tring to change it now. But, even though, the error changed. Now is ```System.IO.FileNotFoundException``` [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dougste/2006/09/05/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-part-1/). But there is some progres. I'll try to change that platform to x64.

Comment: the error in specific says ```System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Wrapper.dll"' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.```
instead of ```System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Wrapper, Version=1.0.7178.20781, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..```
which looks way more solvable to me :D

Comment: [this is](https://i.imgur.com/yl2I96O.png) how my build settings looks like now, and as you can see, I can't change Platform setting to be x64 for the moment.

Comment: Just for the record.
I made it work. After changing platform and target platform to x64, I still got that error. The issue was, that my core project was using an external file in .pt format. Which I obviously added to Core directory. I didn't know that adding that file to C# directory was nessesry also. I call that file in C#, but indirectly. Only by void function that calls another void function which is part of Core project. It is way I thought that I dont need to add that file to C# dir. Anyway, it works now, thanks for your help and your advices :)

Comment: @MateuszBoruch You should post all you learned as answer and accept your own answer instead of mine. I was trying to help, but my answer is not nearly as helpful as your comment, and other people could benefit from it.

Comment: Maybe. I think that if I find a time during weekend I'll create a youtube tutorial where I'll cover all troubles that I faced while building this Solution.
If I do, I will definitely link this video in a separate post in this topic.

It was pretty troublesome to make it work, and I think that this problem deserves to be better covered then it is currently.

Comment: I'm struggling with exactly the same problem, and would really appreciate an answer that contains the required steps!

Comment: @ClareMacrae did you find a solution? Still have the same problem, try to start this example in x64 mode and I get a lot of linker errors.

Comment: @Diddlik sadly not.

Answer (score 1):

This might be incorrect answer... But in my case, I created C++/CLI Wrapper by the same instructions as yours for 32-bit app (named Core) and after that I changed app to 64-bit and I also had the same error. My experience was to create a new one Wrapper project specially for 64-bit Core app (I copied all -h and -cpp files into new project folder and added into project in Solution Explorer). So it's work now. It seems that after wrapping 32-bit dll some links to 32-bit system libraries establish but I can't see it in project's properties. Only creation of new project helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).